# Number pad with dot in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making an app that uses proxies provided by the user. Because the user might not be acquainted with the concept and form of a proxy, I want to limit its keyboard to a numberpad with a dot.

I know that the decimal number pad exists, but that has a comma instead of a dot.

How do I do this? Is there a way to swap the comma for the dot in the decimal number pad?

Comment: You can use the keyboards provided by the system as-is or create a custom keyboard, which _might_ be a bit too much. Also keep in mind that users are used to specific keyboards, from a UX point of view this could be bad anyway.

Comment: FYI - a decimal pad shows either a comma or a dot depending on the user's locale.

Comment: Can I force a locale for that specific keyboard?